# Android How can I click button in website?

Tags: android, button, web

Android How can I click button in website ??

I know Jsoup can't control website.

Can give me some advice??

Comment: will you please explain in detail.you are using webview?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can do this using built in method  `boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url)`. When user click on a button then this method will fire button click URL. After getting the URL you can load the current page using this method `view.loadUrl(url);` I think it will be the best way to handle it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

See this tutorial.Hope you will get an idea.

http://javatechig.com/android/android-webview-example